# change the default magento image background white color to diffrent color

Tags: magento2, css, less

Am attaching the screenshot , want to change image background color.

https://prnt.sc/m2fvyp

Answer (score 0):

> Product image is a media file (like jpeg and a like) . Background color can only be changed by editing the image file.